# Getting user info in an Android Google Authentication with Server Side Verification setup

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-services

I am having some issues in getting Google authentication to work in my android app, using Google Play Services.
First, I used the samples provided with the library to obtain a token using the scope bellow

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity(), mEmail,"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
```

then I used the token to get more info about the user:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + token);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

That worked. Then, I used [Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) post on Google Developers Blog to authenticate the app users to my web server. So I replaced the scope of the getToken with

```
audience:server:client_id:<webapp_clientId_for_localhost>.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

and used a similar checker with the one in the article to verify the audience and clientId (Android Client Id) on the server side. This also worked but, if I try to get more info about the user (first and last name), either from the android app or from the web app, using the userinfo API I get:

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "authError",
>       "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>       "locationType": "header",
>       "location": "Authorization"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "Invalid Credentials"  } }

The code I use is:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
con.setRequestProperty("ContentType", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Any idea why userinfo not working? Is there something else I should add to the scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token you use for backend verification is intended for your server, while the one with oauth2: is intended for Google. At this point in time there's no mechanism to request both tokens simultaneously, so you need to make two calls to GoogleAuthUtil. You should be able to request both (one at a time) after a single consent step. In practice, the oauth2: token should be needed less frequently, as you can associate the user's profile data w/ the account you have from them in your home server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Hey @breno, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: Oops, didn't notice this question. Are you still experiencing the issue?